# Why do businesses in Cambodia require pristine bank notes when customers pay in USD?

Tags: payment, cash, cambodia

Businesses in Cambodia require pristine bank notes when customers pay in USD. E.g., 1) a slightly torn USD bank note will typically be refused 2) If anything was written on the bank note by an individual, it'll get rejected if the writing is detected by the business. Meanwhile, one could use a USD bank note as toilet paper in the US and use it as a means of payment without any issue in the USA. Why do businesses in Cambodia require pristine bank notes when customers pay in USD?

Comment: It's a bit surprising they accept foreign currency at all, given counterfeit risk. I can't blame them for wanting something easier to examine

Comment: "Meanwhile, one could use a USD bank note as toilet paper in the US and use it as a means of payment without any issue in the USA. " This is a ridiculous exaggeration. Merchants in the US refuse defaced, unfit currency all the time. You do have the option of returning unfit currency to a Federal Reserve Bank, but even then [special procedures have to be followed for contaminated currency](https://www.frbservices.org/resources/financial-services/cash/exception-processing/contaminated-coin-currency.html).

Answer (score 6):

It is hard to know for certain why many people behave in a particular way.  But the most likely answer here is that it minimizes counterfeit risk.

If you are going to counterfeit US currency, it's much easier to get away with if you set up shop in Southeast Asia than if you set up in the Southeast US.  The Secret Service is likely to sniff out the US operation pretty quickly.  Coordinating with foreign governments and police forces takes a lot more time and effort.  So the baseline risk that a bill is counterfeit is higher in a foreign country than in the US.

A worn or damaged counterfeit is easier to pass off than a pristine note.  If the counterfeiting process fails to replicate some microprinting or doesn't produce a crisp portrait, it is easier to overlook that on a worn bill than on a crisp one.  And since two new bills look identical but two worn bills may have different wear patterns, it is easier to get an intuitive feel that one of the crisp bills is somehow "off" from the counterfeit process than if you're looking at a torn or worn bill.

Only accepting new bills also ensures that only the current design is accepted.  The US $100 bill was redesigned in 1996 and again in 2013.  The Treasury regularly updates designs to incorporate new security features.  If bills are circulating and getting used as they are commonly in the US, they are likely to wear out pretty quickly and be replaced by the new series.  If bills are just being held, they wear out more slowly.  If you accept only crisp, new bills, you only need to train your clerks on how to spot counterfeits in the current series of bill designs.  If you accept the $100 bill that's been sitting under someone's mattress for 30 years, you have to recognize 2 or 3 different designs for each bill which increases the risk that you'll accept a counterfeit.

Comment: Bills can spend years in a mattress and still be crisp... Just sayin...